# PostgreSQLpgagent "Running at: is not runing"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgagent

I have a problem to run pgAgent job for PostgreSQL 9.6 under ubuntu 16.04.
The job is never executed.

I already configured .pgpass and added:

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:mypass
```

Also modified the permission for .pgpass:

```
$ touch ~/.pgpass
$ chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass
```

After that I run pgAgent with no problem:

```
$pgagent hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=mydb user=postgres
```

When I check the process for pgAgent I would get this result:

```
user@gis-srv:~$ ps aux | grep pgagent
user   153179  0.0  0.0 113844  9392 pts/26   S    17:15   0:00 pgagent hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgres user=postgres
user   153220  0.0  0.0 113844  9360 pts/26   S    17:16   0:00 pgagent hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=mydb user=postgres
user   153227  0.0  0.0  12944   936 pts/26   S+   17:16   0:00 grep --color=auto pgagent
```

Here is my job setting:

 Job Setting:

[image: Job Setting]

Schedule setting:

[image: Schedule setting]

Step Setting:

[image: Step Setting]

My propblen that the job is never executed and there is no error in the errors log for PostgreSQL. 
Please help me to find out why jobs never run.

I am receving the following errors:
from postgres.log:

```
2017-11-03 16:01:32.269 EDT [15344] postgres@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

from pgagent.log:

```
(attempt 9): fe_sendauth: no password supplied
Fri Nov  3 16:01:32 2017 : WARNING: Couldn't create the primary connection (attempt 10): fe_sendauth: no password supplied
Fri Nov  3 16:01:32 2017 : ERROR: Stopping pgAgent: Couldn't establish the primary connection with the database server.
```

Also I modified the permission .pgpass to allow everyone to access it. (Just for testing)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Evan My propblen that the job is never executed and there is no error in the errors log for PostgreSQL Please help me to find out why jobs never run.

Comment: Try specifying the ‘-s </path/to/pgagent.log>’ option when starting pgagent. I’m going to assume the ‘asselect’ code just looks funny in the image, else that will definitely raise a syntax error.

Comment: @Evan I am getting this error from pgagent log 

Fri Nov  3 13:20:54 2017 : WARNING: Couldn't create the primary connection (attempt 10): fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Fri Nov  3 13:20:54 2017 : ERROR: Stopping pgAgent: Couldn't establish the primary connection with the database server.

Comment: As I mentioned I already setup .pgpass with required information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're specifying

`pgagent hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=mydb user=postgres`

change .pgpass to match it

`127.0.0.1:5432:*:postgres:mypass`

or specify

`*:5432:*:postgres:mypass`

Edit: And change the permissions of .pgpass back to 0600 else you'll get the message:

`WARNING: password file "~/.pgpass" has group or world access; permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less`

and for command line, it prompts for password

Comment: I updated .pgpass to *:5432:*:postgres:mypass
and change the permissions for others to Read and write 

and I am still getting error as 

Wed Nov  8 16:55:44 2017 : WARNING: Couldn't create the primary connection (attempt 10): fe_sendauth: no password supplied
Wed Nov  8 16:55:44 2017 : ERROR: Stopping pgAgent: Couldn't establish the primary connection with the database server.

Comment: It has to be `*:5432:*:postgres:mypass` and not `5432::postgres:mypass` permission on the file should be `-rw------`

Comment: sorry that was typo I added what you what you wrote *:5432:*:postgres:mypas and change permission to -rw------ and same result

Comment: I've setup a ubuntu server, and i get `Failed to query jobs table!`. I will try and create a job later. Can you try one more thing please? export PGPASSWORD=mypass; pgagent -s pgagent.log ho...

Comment: And sorry but i have to ask, I'm assuming the psql command is not working either? `psql 'hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=mydb user=postgres' `

Comment: IT is working with psql

Comment: That's wierd. The PGPASSWORD btw has to work. Ensure that you stop/kill all pgagent processes

Comment: After restarting the server it is working now Thank you so much for your help amacvar